# HttpSession request.getSession(false)

Tags: java, session, glassfish

I have a problem. In my `servlet` in glassfish I call the method `request.getSession(false)`. It should `return null`. But instead there is always a `session` returned. 
Moreover, if I `invalidate` the `session` right before the call to `getSession(false)` - it `returns null`. It means something else creates the `session`!
What could that be? 
The `servlet` is redirected from the .jsp page. I am using the glassfish.

Comment: Are you using something like spring security?

Comment: It should only return null if there isn't a session established.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you disabled the session in JSP? At the top of your jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" session="false"%>
```

Comment: actually not. It helped. Why does it happen like that?

Comment: if it does not return null, you should make sure you know what creates it. doing this is not a solution. it might kill the session needed by other part of your web application.

Comment: @gigadot, No need to search, it is the JSP page, JSP pages always create a session unless you explicitly says to not do that... Why? I would say it's just a conception choice.

Comment: http://www.techper.net/2008/07/21/a-jsp-file-always-creates-a-session/ might be helpful