# Concurrent HTTP Session is returning wrong user

Tags: java, session, struts, struts-1

I am experiencing a quite weird problem. When two users are logging at the exact same time, one of them is detected as the other.

```
    locale = new Locale(getLocale(request).getLanguage(), getLocale(request).getCountry());


    strRemoteUser = WebTools.getUserIdWithoutDomainName(request.getRemoteUser()).toUpperCase();

    logger.info("[MYAPP] User " + strRemoteUser + " is logging in");

    logger.info("[MYAPP] Creating session for : " + strRemoteUser);

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    if (session != null) {

        session.invalidate();
        session = request.getSession();
    }       

    logger.info("[MYAPP] User in session is : " + strRemoteUser);
```

What I get is the following. Let's assume that two users (USR001 and USR002) are logging to the application at the same exact time. They are located in a different location.

Logs:

```
    2013-05-14 08:19:38,550 INFO  [com.myapp.action.common.LoginAction] [MYAPP] User USR001 is logging in
2013-05-14 08:19:38,551 INFO  [com.myapp.action.common.LoginAction] [MYAPP] Creating session for : USR001
2013-05-14 08:19:38,760 INFO  [com.myapp.action.common.LoginAction] [MYAPP] User USR002 is logging in
2013-05-14 08:19:38,761 INFO  [com.myapp.action.common.LoginAction] [MYAPP] Creating session for : USR002
2013-05-14 08:19:38,834 INFO  [com.myapp.action.common.LoginAction] [MYAPP] User in session is : USR002
2013-05-14 08:19:39,104 INFO  [com.myapp.action.common.LoginAction] [MYAPP] User in session is : USR002
2013-05-14 08:19:39,425 INFO  [com.myapp.action.common.LoginAction] [MYAPP] Auto Added User USR002
2013-05-14 08:19:39,550 INFO  [com.myapp.action.common.LoginAction] [MYAPP] Setting user in session: USR002 (673)
```

As you can see, USR002 "wins" the concurrent session creation as USR001 is now recognized as USR002. If USR001 logs out and then log back in, it works properly.

Any thoughts/advice?

Thank you very much for help.

Specs:

- jBoss 4.2.3GA
- PostgreSQL 9.0.3
- Struts 1.3.5
- EJB3

Comment: Is strRemoteUser a class variable ? Also, if you are using a JSP, check this response : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10778311/1083581

Comment: Yes it is a class variable. Is it a good practice?

Comment: We are using a JSP with only a <logic:forward name="login" /> statement so the LoginAction action is fired. The code I have pasted is directly placed in the "execute" method of LoginAction. My JSP already has <%@ page language="java" session="false"%> in its header.

Comment: These are classic concurrency issues, if we are talking about the same thing. Move the variable into the method and run it again and look at the output.

Comment: So did it fix your problem ? If yes, I can write my comments as an answer and you can mark it accepted :) .. or we can continue to debug

Comment: I will know it tomorrow as the application is heavily used now so a deployment needs to be done outside business hours. I am 99% sure it will work using your suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: Struts 1 actions are just like servlets; using instance variables requires a bit of effort, and is almost never actually what you want. If the app is in heavy use, you're lucky it hasn't caused major, major issues, if the entire app was written like this.

Comment: Only the login mechanism is coded that way. It should be okay by now. Thanks guys!

Comment: @happybuddha: You can post it as an answer. It solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am glad it helped. Here's the comment posted as an 
answer : These are classic concurrency issues, if we are talking about the same thing. Move the variable into the method and run it again and look at the output.

Answer (score 1):

Many developers are missing the fact that Struts 1 uses *single instance* of `Action` to serve requests from all sessions, so `Action`s should be written in concurrent-safe manner, e.g.

- use only immutable (final) fields
- use local variables instead of mutable fields
- be aware of thread-unsafe classes like `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Matcher`

Of course there are many more subtle issues, and there are many resources to learn from (e.g. Java Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz).

P.S. [Action Class Design Guidelines](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/userGuide/building_controller.html#action_design_guide) from the original Apache Struts documentation

Comment: Thank you for the additional info. Much appreciated.